# Problem with Sharepoint Ribbon

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ribbon

I have a problem with Ribbon on a site, it looks like image below. This view appear in all ribbons in the site.

[image]

Note: I didn't edit anything in the site

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Use IE Developer Toolbar or Chrome's Inspect element to check what CSS is getting applied to these buttons.. My guess is there is some custom CSS of yours which is causing this issue!

Answer (score 3):

1. Try resizing your browser window (which browser are you using?)
2. Change the browser zoom level (know bugs with that)
3. Check for any JavaScript errors while loading the page
4. Try to remove all custom CSS/branding - that is does it behave the same on a default non customized site?

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me when I use low resolution screen, may I suggest that you take a look at it on a screen with higher resolution?